# Traversal in tree/linked list structure

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree, traversal

[image: This is what my structure looks like]

It is kind of like a hybrid tree/linked list structure. Here's how I defined the structure

```
struct node {
    nodeP sibling;
    nodeP child;
    nodeP parent;
    char name[100];    
};
```

a node has a child, that is connected to a linked list. Other elements on the linked list may have their own child that is connected to the linked list or by itself

Now to my question, how would I traverse this structure to search and print the path to a specific node.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Update
Here is printPath function:

```
//node -> root of the tree
//current = this is the node that i need to print path to

void printPath(nodeP node, nodeP current){ 

    if (node != NULL){
        if ((strcmp(node->name, current->name) == 0))
        {
            printf("%s/", node->name);
            return; //it returns to the previous recursive call and then continues until the node is null
        }
        printPath(root->childDir, currentDir);
        printPath(root->sibling, currentDir);
        printf(" %s/", node->name);
    }
}
```

My problem is getting out of the recursive call, once if finish printing path to the current node.

Comment: I don't see relation between the image and the code. `parent` and `child` pointers are suggesting on a bi-directional connectivity between nodes.

Comment: for simplicity I added the parent poiner. I could remove that if that is nor helpful

Comment: If we take out the `parent` thing, we are staying with a regular binary tree, which is using names `child` and `sibling` instead of `left` and `right`. So traverse it in any commonly used technique for binary trees.

Comment: I followed what you said and wrote a printPath function. I will update the function up in the question. But the problem is, when I find the node that i am looking for, i need to exit out of the recursive function. How would I do that?

Comment: I will write it as an answer, if you don't mind, due to better formatting options.

Comment: Sure. That would be great! And thanks

Comment: Did you want the path printed from root to node (top down) or from node to root (bottom up)?     If the later, then having the parent pointer makes it really simple since you don't have to search for anything, you just follow the parent nodes from the given node until you get to the top (parent=null)

Comment: from root to the node (top down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node structure presented in the question is the same as for a regular binary tree which is using names `child` and `sibling` instead of the traditional `left` and `right`.
If you want to print a path to the desired node, you should print the *root* values of each *subtree* containing that node. So here is the pseudocode:

```
function printPath(root, searchName)
    if root is null
         return false
    if root.name is searchName or 
       printPath(root.child, searchName) or
       printPath(root.sibling, searchName) then
         print root.name
         return true
    else
        return false
```

Here, if root is null, it is not containing the desired node, so we return false for this path printing nothing. But if it's name is the one that we want, or one of it's subtrees is containing what we want, we print the name and returning true. This way you will get the path printed in the order from the leaf to root.

Comment: How would i reverse it. I want it printed from root to the node.

Comment: You will have to pass an additional array parameter along, which will store the path instead of printing it. Or make it global and push the values in it instead of printing. An then just print in in the order you want.

Comment: That helps! Thanks. I'll go ahead and accept your answer